# Spark convert csv with Excel formula and get only the value

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark, bigdata

I have a CSV file with a column something like =HYPERLINK ("www.google.com","contact us"). So this file was converted from Excel to CSV and it retained that formula. I need only the hyperlink and not contact us.

So is there a way I can identify whether this file has some Excel formula? If yes then how will I convert this.

I am using spark and Scala

Comment: There is no solution out of the box for this one. You'll need to do it yourself.

Comment: Do you have the best approach in your mind?